# WPF joystick control

Tags: wpf

I would like to create a joystick (x,y) control based on [C# WPF - Virtual joystick using polar coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37421431/c-sharp-wpf-virtual-joystick-using-polar-coordinates).

How can I animate (like a spring) the knob returning to its central position after the mouse button is released?

Comment: What I would do is check if the mouse button is released, if it is, subtract a small amount from the x and y positions until they go back to 0. Or you could ease it by doing something like this: `x *= 0.8f;`

Comment: In `WPF` use animations with easing functions [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/easing-functions)

Comment: I have tried easing functions, and they return knob to center, but when FillBehavior="HoldEnd", knob can't move after animation. If i set FillBehavior="Stop" knob returns to dragged position after animation is done….